# Can I use the Skyrim console to increase the number of available perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Short version: player.addperk isn't working like I want it to.

Is there a way I can change the number of available perk choices that I have?  Basically I want to level myself without increasing my level or my magic/health/stamina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specify which perk code to add.

You can make a [batch file](http://www.gamefront.com/skyrim-add-every-perk-on-pc/) to add them all in one command or add them [one by one](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Perk_Codes_%28Skyrim%29).

Comment: When you do this, does it light up the node in the UI like you actually added the perk?  I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Also, I find it hard to believe that there isn't a command to modify the 'AvailablePerkCount' value somehow.

Comment: Oooh that is interesting. So it might be possible for a web based "character build" to generate a bat that you can use in-game to apply the build.

Comment: Yes faB that's definitely possible.

Krazer - player.addperk seems to do what I want, maybe I was using it wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: `addperk` is basically broken; it'll often look like it worked (as far as the tree is concerned) but not actually have any effect.

Comment: @Aarobot I haven't had this problem, did you make sure you're adding the new perk(s) in logical order (have the prerequisite perk and/or skill point requirement)?